# adding Outlook library to access VBA prevents SAP createsession from working

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016, sap-gui

SAP GUI code CreateSession when I add the Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library, a Session is never created. If I remove the outlook reference it works fine.

The outlook code is on another form that the user of THIS form doesn't use so its not executed.

Since this problem was identified in 2010 on the SAP site back in 2010 and nothing else , I'll assume its in the way this code is written.

I'm using SAP GUI Scripting API

Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library

SAP version is 7.50

thanks

Peter

```
Session_number_max = 5                                  'the maximum number of possible SAP sessions
Dim session_number_(5)
 On Error Resume Next
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SAP = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = SAP.Children(0)
Set session = Connection.Children(0)
'------------------------------------------- new session connect -------------------------------------------------------------
session_number_all = Connection.Children.Count - 1
If Connection.Children.Count = 0 Then
 'MsgBox ("Couts =") & session_number_all
 'GoTo Erreur
 End If
For i = 0 To Session_number_max - 1
     session_number_(i) = 0
Next
For session_number = 0 To session_number_all
     Set session = Connection.Children(Int(session_number))
     session_number_(session.Info.SessionNumber) = session.Info.SessionNumber
Next
If session_number_all < Session_number_max - 1 Then
      Do
trycount = trycount + 1

      
     session.CreateSession                                              '#### this ends up in an infinite loop as CreateSession never creates a valid session.  ####
 'WScript.sleep 500
      If Connection.Children.Count - session_number_all >= 2 Then Exit Do   '#### this ends up in an infinite loop as 
     
If trycount >5 then 

exit loop

GoTo Errorcode

end if
Loop
     On Error Resume Next
     Error_number = 1
     For session_number = 0 To session_number_all + 1
          Err.Clear
          Set session = Connection.Children(Int(session_number + 1))
          If Err.Number > 0 Or Err.Number < 0 Then Exit For
      'MsgBox (" Session = ") & session_number
         If session_number_(session.Info.SessionNumber) = 0 Then
            Error_number = 0
            Exit For
         End If
         'session.findById("wnd[0]").iconify                          'So you can send another SAP session in the task bar.
     Next
     On Error GoTo 0
Else
 MsgBox "Nouvelle session pas possible!"
End If
```

Comment: Might help to show all of your variable delarations (and make sure you're using Option Explicit)   Adding a reference to Outlook will put all of those related object types "in play" so opens up possible confusion between your `session` variable and the outlook `Application.Session` for example.  You might need to be more explicit in your declarations.

Comment: All variables are in the code above , I added option explicit. The Outlook code is on another form and is not accessed by this user. It only when I added the Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library that it bugs SAP. Since the only other reference to this exact problem is from 2010 and I can't find any other reference , I assume its with the SAP code above!

Comment: Where is `Dim session` ?  I'm asking about **declarations**

Comment: Well Tim , you found my solution not with your answer but with your question, "where is the Dim session" LOL. Problem is I didn't have one. Just added Dim Session As SAPFEWSELib.GuiSession  and it works WITH the Outlook library. Take out the Dim, it stops working. Really weird as the code was working since 2016 until I added the Outlook library for another users application! Thanks

Comment: I think they're related - until you added the outlook library there was nothing to "confuse" the runtime when it finds an undeclared and untyped `session` variable - it could not match it to anything else, so it was just treated like a regular variable.  After adding the outlook library, the runtime looks in its referenced object models for something called "session" and now finds a match in the outlook object model: that's how your problem came up.